# Flexbox with shrinked image has width of original image size (not collapsing to rendered image width)

Tags: html, css, flexbox, image-resizing

A flex container with an image which is beeing shrinked to fit the containers height keeps the width of the original image before it was resized. So the container does not collapse to the new width of the shrinked image.

See the hatched area around the tire:

[image: Image of uncollapsed flexbox]

It's about the tire image.

Original Image  size: 292x440px

Rendered Image Size: 137x206px

Size of div.cont_1: 292px (should be/would like to have ;) 137px)

Code is as follows:
Example HTML:

```css
.cont_1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.cont_2 {
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cont_3 {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont_1">
  <div class="cont_2">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/292x440/000/fff" class="" alt="alt-text">
  </div>
  <div class="cont_3">Title</div>
</div>
```

How do I get rid of that space around that image.

In the end I'd like to have the tire and the title nicely centered over each other with no annoying space around them.

Comment: Can you give us more context of your problem? With some extra code or something, because I don't see the problem.

Comment: I added a 292x440px dummy image to your question, please elaborate further on the issue. The "hatched area" around the image resembles either margins/spacing or a defined width of `cont_2` that the image does not fill. However, I don't see it present in the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

In .cont_1 change:

display: flex;
to
display: inline-flex;

This should prevent the parent container from stretching across the screen and remove the extra space within.

```css
.cont_1 {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.cont_2 {
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cont_3 {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont_1">
  <div class="cont_2">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/292x440/000/fff" class="" alt="alt-text">
  </div>
  <div class="cont_3">Title</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want like this:

```css
.cont_1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: max-content;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.cont_2 {
  width: 30%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.cont_3 {
  text-align: center;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont_1">
  <div class="cont_2">
    <img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/5c29cf910a706_8m.jpg" class="" alt="alt-text">
  </div>
  <div class="cont_3">Title</div>
</div>
```